# How to disable commas on Integer field in Edit item screen

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, integer, custom-field-type

I have a field defined as this:

```
<Field Type="Integer" DisplayName="BŠS" Required="FALSE" Commas="FALSE" Group="CRPU grupa" ID="{f8ae007e-df89-4149-8318-a79673cec338}" SourceID="{e0015c45-f539-484b-ae04-b792801053e3}" StaticName="BŠS" Name="BŠS"  />
```

This is a part of a custom content type, which is added to a list. When I display an item, the field displays ok, without commas (or points depending on the language pack I guess)

> BŠS 434343

but if I try to edit, it shows them like this:

> BŠS  434.343

Is there any way of changing this behaviour?

This is on Moss 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a custom field template for your field (i.e. if this field is deployed as a feature or the whole list template is a feature), you can create a custom field template and use it in your forms (see instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414.aspx)
However, it *will not* apply to different views of your list as well as it will not work in datasheet editor mode.